# android adding images over other images

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to programatically add an image over another image using ImageView (if possible).  I also need to be able to use tween animation on it later.  I am an amateur coder so sorry for this basic question.  What I have is below, I understand other parts of coding well but I've never done anything graphical before which is why I am struggling with this.  Again I am very sorry as I am just trying to learn a new area of coding.

```
    LinearLayout myLinearLayout; 
    myLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
    ImageView myView = new ImageView(this); 
    myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.base_image); 
    myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    myLinearLayout.addView(myView);
    setContentView(myLinearLayout);

    LinearLayout imageLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    imageLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    imageLayout.setLayoutParams(vp);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.testicon);
    image.setLayoutParams(vp);

    myLinearLayout.addView(imageLayout);
    setContentView(myLinearLayout);
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` to perform this action.

Comment: @ Bill I wrote an answer to your question. Please let me know your idea.

Answer (score 0):

As `Anggrayudi` said, you should use `RelativeLayout` instead of first `LinearLayout`.
Then you should make `vp` with `LinearLayout` for assigning it to second image.

I have edited your code as follow:

```
    RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout;
    myRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ImageView myView = new ImageView(this);
    myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.base_image);
    myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    myRelativeLayout.addView(myView);
    setContentView(myRelativeLayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.testicon);
    image.setLayoutParams(vp);

    myRelativeLayout.addView(image);
```

Pay attention that I have removed some unnecessary lines.
Hope to be helpful.